# two-way binding between object attribute array (enum on server) and ember checkbox group

Tags: ember.js

I am looking for a solution to bind an object attribute that contains an array of string (representing an enum on the server) to a list of checkboxes. The binding should be two-way.

On the server, we have some enum defintion, e.g., Role with the values "ADMIN", "GUEST", "USER". A user object may have several of thus roles, thus the user object in Ember is of the form

```
App.User = Ember.Object.create({
    roles: ["USER", "ADMIN"]
});
```

In the user administration, there should be a group of checkboxes. One checkbox per role. So, it is possible to select none, all, or several.

I know that there is the `Ember.Checkbox` view that can be used for this. What I am looking for would be a easy and generic view to handle any kind of enums as mentioned above.

Thus, the questions are:

- has somebody a nice solution for this?
- does anybody know a opensource project providing such extensions to ember?

Thanks in advance. // ph

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A generic way to handle a two way binding between an Ember object and Checkboxes can be implemented using plain Ember.js without the need of any plugins if you are willing to sync the enums on the server and the client manually (using AJAX or WebSockets). Note that Ember can update the list of options with Checkbox automatically after a sync.

So henceforth, I will assume that you have am enum with roles as an Ember Array:

```js
App.Roles = [ "USER", "ADMIN", "GUEST" ];
```

Then we will show the options available to the user in a [CollectionView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html) like this (the template is given below).

```js
OptionsView = Em.CollectionView.extend({
    contentBinding: 'App.Roles',  // Show a list of _all_ available roles
    userBinding: 'App.User',      // This points to the active user
    tagName: 'ul',                // Shown as a <ul>
    itemViewClass: Em.View.extend({
        userBinding: 'parentView.user',  // For convenience
        templateName: 'user-roles' // Defined later
    })
});
```

The template for each option is:

```html
<script data-template-name="user-roles" type="text/x-handlebars">
  <label> {{view App.RoleCheckbox 
            contentBinding="view.content"}} 
  {{view.content}}
  </label>
</script>
```

Note that the use of `<label>` tag makes sure that the Checkbox's `click` event is fired on clicking anywhere on the tag.

Finally the `App.RoleCheckbox` is an extension of the `Ember.Checkbox` class which handles the `checked` property and `click` event to toggle the role:

```js
App.RoleCheckbox = Em.Checkbox.extend({
    userRolesBinding: 'parentView.user.roles', // Points to the roles of the user

    checked: function () {
        var userRoles = this.get('userRoles');
        return userRoles.contains(this.get('content'));
    }.property('content', 'userRoles.@each'),

    click: function (evt) {
        var isPresent = this.get('checked'),
            userRoles = this.get('userRoles'),
            role      = this.get('content');

         if (!isPresent) { 
             userRoles.pushObject(role); 
         } else {
             userRoles.removeObject(role);
         }
     }
});
```

An working example of this is: http://jsfiddle.net/BLQBf/ (Look at the console to see the log messages)

Note that this is not completely Ember-esque, since the View is doing part of the job meant for the `controller`. Ideally, the `click` event would call a function on the `RoleCheckboxController` which would make changes to the `User` object.

Comment: thanks @musically_ut for the answer. I had to postpone my implementation of this, so my comment comes late. Your solution works, but there was a small issue. The observer on `checked` triggers before the click event. There I had to revert the if-else statement triggered by the click event.

Comment: @musically_ut, I asked a question about how to make the call to the RoleCheckboxController as you suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281401/ember-how-to-create-and-bind-a-checkbox-controller), but I could not make it work.

Comment: already triggered an edit on the answer of @musically_ut. It is currently peer reviewed. Until it is reviewed. please use the "change" event instead of the "click" event because of browser compatibility. See also https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2604

Comment: I updated the resources links to Ember/Handlebars, since previous jsfiddle stopped working.
http://jsfiddle.net/BLQBf/8/

Comment: beware that checked gets overwritten if the checkbox is clicked. it is better to make checked also a setter (give it two arguments). that way the click handler is also obsoleted.