# List of checkboxes values as array like Ember.Select (multiple)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to get the data of a list of checkboxes in Ember as an array of id's?

In my app I want to make a new Site. I made a route to `/sites/new` to show a form with fields to add a Site.

This is my Model:

```
App.Site = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
    languages: DS.hasMany('App.Language')
});
App.Language = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string')
});
```

This is my Controller:

```
app.SitesNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    needs : [ 'languages' ],
    name: null,
    languages: null,
    createSite : function() {
        // Get the site name
        var name = this.get('name');
        var languages = this.get('languages');
        console.log(name,description,languages);
        // Create the new Site model
        app.Site.createRecord({
            name : name,
            languages : languages
        });

        // Save the new model
        this.get('store').commit();
    }
});
```

This is (part of) my SitesNewView:

```
{{#each controllers.languages}}
    <label class="checkbox">
        {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="languages"}}
        {{ name }}
    </label>
{{/each}} 
<button {{ action "createSite" }}>Save</button>
```

In my console languages is `null`. How do I get an array of language-id's out of `this.get('languages')`?

**UPDATE**

I mean something like an Ember.Select with attribute `multiple=true`, like this: `{{view Ember.Select selectionBinding="languages" contentBinding="controllers.languages" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name" multiple="true"}}`

Comment: I asked a question which is similar to it and got a good answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665026/two-way-binding-between-object-attribute-array-enum-on-server-and-ember-checkb

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/durinthomas/cB3De/) that I quickly created.

This may not be the best solution but at least it should help you.