# Ember - how to create and bind a Checkbox controller?

Tags: ember.js

This question is linked to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14666598/1011366).

Having a checkbox in a view

```
App.RoleCheckbox = Em.Checkbox.extend({
    userRolesBinding: 'parentView.user.roles', // Points to the roles of the user

    checked: function () {
        var userRoles = this.get('userRoles');
        return userRoles.contains(this.get('content'));
    }.property('content', 'userRoles.@each'),

    click: function (evt) {
        //do something
        var controller = this.get("controller");
        controller.clicked(evt);
     }
});
```

I would like that the click function calls the clicked function from the RoleCheckboxController:

```
App.RoleCheckboxController = Em.Controller.extend({
    clicked: function(evt){
        //Really do the thing
    }
});
```

But this does not work. How could I fix this ?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fMpD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate and associate the controller to the view using the correct [naming conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/).

For example, this would associate the controller to the view:

```
// Instead of App.RoleCheckBoxController
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend( /* ... */ );
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend( /* .. */ );
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YL5rQ/

Comment: thank you, it clarified things to me. I edited your answer to show part of your jsfiddle code

Comment: Another question: I don't understand the bindings you use. Which doc or tutorial should I read to get a better understanding of userRolesBinding, ... you used ? I am not able to re-use this as a subview of another app

Comment: I think the edit was not approved for some reason. And there are two `userRolesBinding` in my answer: `userRolesBinding: 'parentView.user.roles'` (which is detailed [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/)) and `userRolesBinding: 'user.roles'` which is a simple binding.

Comment: Well, I thought I had made a copy paste from your jsFiddle. Maybe I missed something. Thank you for the links about bindings, I am beginning to understand how they work now.

Answer (score 1):

@c4p is definitely right and the problem there is that your controller is not being created, and furthermore `App.RoleCheckbox` has no way of knowing it should use `App.RoleCheckboxController` as its controller.

I am not quite sure if this is the most *Ember-y* way of doing this but you can set the controller in the `init` (**constructor function**) of the Checkbox view, and then just make sure you `send` to the controller all the properties it needs to work with:

```
App.RoleCheckbox = Em.Checkbox.extend({

    init: function(){
      this._super();
      this.set('controller', new App.RoleController());  
    },

    userRolesBinding: 'parentView.user.roles',

    checked: function () {
        var userRoles = this.get('userRoles');
        return userRoles.contains(this.get('content'));
    }.property('content', 'userRoles.@each'),

    click: function (evt) {
        this.get('controller').send('clicked',this.checked, this.content);
     }
});
```

And the controller's code (just changing the parameters used in the function);

```
App.RoleCheckboxController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    clicked: function(checked,role){

         var userRoles = App.User.roles;

         console.log("userRoles = ", userRoles);
         console.log("role = ", role);
         console.log("will be: ", !checked ? "removed" : "added");

         if (checked) { 
             userRoles.pushObject(role); 
         } else {
             userRoles.removeObject(role);
         }

         console.log("updated userRoles = ", userRoles);

    }
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cfSwq/3/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it helped me in the understanding of this. I don't know if it is possible to re-use an existing instance of an object, that would be a best approach, but this one seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `App.RoleCheckboxController` is never created.  The way you have things set up there will only be an instance of `ApplicationController`.

You can move the logic back into the view's `click` event to have everything work:

```
App.RoleCheckbox = Em.Checkbox.extend({
    userRolesBinding: 'parentView.user.roles',

    checked: function () {
        var userRoles = this.get('userRoles');
        return userRoles.contains(this.get('content'));
    }.property('content', 'userRoles.@each'),

    click: function (evt) {
        console.log("event triggered:", evt);
        //var controller = this.get("controller");
        //controller.clicked(evt);
        var isPresent = this.get('checked'),
            userRoles = this.get('userRoles'),
            role = this.get('content');

         console.log("userRoles = ", userRoles);
         console.log("role = ", role);
         console.log("will be: ", isPresent ? "removed" : "added");

         if (!isPresent) { 
             userRoles.pushObject(role); 
         } else {
             userRoles.removeObject(role);
         }
     }
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fMpD/1/)

Comment: Actually, what you wrote is the original solution I had (see the first link of my question). I would like to put the business logic (the part inside the click function) in a controller's function.